# javascript webservice call and settimeout

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, settimeout, setinterval

i'm currently developing an application that relies on webservice calls in order to create a tree-like "menu", everything works as intended but i realized not all the target audience has a fast internet connection like i have right now on the development environment. my goal is to show a loading "screen" while the javascript function creates and then adds the elements to the DOM, the flowchart is as follows:

1. user click on the "expand" image of a node
2. user sees a div loading gif
3. user is presented with the childnodes

i'm not sure where i should put the timeout

my code:

```
...
elemento_tema_imagem_esconde_mostra.addEventListener("click", Get_Feat);
...

function Get_Feat(event) {
    Tema_Expandido = event.target.parentNode;


    if (typeof (Tema_Expandido.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]) === "undefined") {
        sMNID = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("mnid");

        var service = new WebJSON;
        service.GetFeat(sMNID, SuccessCallback_Get_Feat, OnfailureCallback_Get_Feat);

    } else {

        //debugger;
        var elemento = Tema_Expandido.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
        var imagem_esconder_mostar = elemento.parentNode.childNodes[0];
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(elemento, null);
        if (style.display == "block") {
            elemento.style.display = "none";
            imagem_esconder_mostar.src = "Content/Images/img_abrir_22_22.png";
        } else if (style.display == "none") {
            elemento.style.display = "block";
            imagem_esconder_mostar.src = "Content/Images/img_fechar_22_22.png";
        }


    }


};


function SuccessCallback_Get_Feat(Resultado_Get_Feat) {
    var colleccao_Feat = JSON.parse(Resultado_Get_Feat);

    var lista_feat = document.createElement("ul");
    lista_feat.setAttribute("class", "lista-sem-bullets");
    for (var i = 0; i < colleccao_Feat.length; i++) {

        var elemento_feat = document.createElement("li");
        var elemento_feat_imagem_esconde_mostra = document.createElement("img");
        var elemento_feat_imagem_no = document.createElement("img");
        var elemento_feat_link = document.createElement("a");

        if (colleccao_Feat[i].FILHOS > 0) {
            elemento_feat_imagem_esconde_mostra.src = "Content/Images/img_abrir_22_22.png";
            elemento_feat_imagem_esconde_mostra.addEventListener("click", Get_Compo);
        } else if (colleccao_Feat[i].FILHOS = 0) {
            elemento_feat_imagem_esconde_mostra.src = "Content/Images/seta_dir_26_20.png";
        }

        //elemento_feat_imagem_esconde_mostra.addEventListener("click", Get_Feat);

        //elemento_feat_imagem_no.src = "Content/Images/feat.png"

        elemento_feat_link.setAttribute("FNID", colleccao_Feat[i].FNID);
        elemento_feat_link.innerText = colleccao_Feat[i].NAMEDESC;

        elemento_feat.appendChild(elemento_feat_imagem_esconde_mostra);
        elemento_feat.appendChild(elemento_feat_imagem_no);
        elemento_feat.appendChild(elemento_feat_link);

        lista_feat.appendChild(elemento_feat);
    };

    document.getElementById("myModal_Loading").style.display = "none";
    Tema_Expandido.appendChild(lista_feat);
    Tema_Expandido.childNodes[0].src = "Content/Images/img_fechar_22_22.png";
};

function OnfailureCallback_Get_Feat(error) {
    //displaying error on alert box    
    alert(error);
};
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: what is the purpose of the setTimeout - knowing it's purpose will help you decide where to put it (if you even need it that is, which I suspect you wont)

Comment: the purpose is to show a loading screen while i consume the webservice and add the elements to the DOM, i do need it because some lower levels have complicated queries that take a bit longer to process and i don't want the user to click the same thing twice in a row